# Storing many files as one

Tags: partitioning, images

I want to keep hundreds of thousands of small files into one image because copying and moving such a load is a nightmare. I want to be able to mount this image under both Windows and Linux and create symlinks to folders of applications which are using it. I know that usage iso image wouldn't work as it is read only. I read about raw images (created with dd), but I cannot find option to make it resizable. Do you know some solutions for such situation?

Comment: Is there some reason a normal folder/directory doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: Yes, I must sometimes move those files and while I can copy smaller amount of big files -- I can do it with full drive speed. Copying ~300 000 of 1 - 4 sec mp3 recordings takes ages.

Comment: Put them in .rar or .zip archive?

Comment: Program which uses those files requires direct access to them, like  in normal folder.

Answer (score 1):

A shared FAT partition would be your best bet.

1) Can mount under both OSes

2) Can symlink things

3) Can also copy the entire partition logically/physically and stick someplace else.

Comment: The last point seams to be most tricky, and I have to set fixed size that partition must occupy (increasing it is even trickier). Now I think there is no good solution (or I'll try to mount zip file as partition and see how it works). Anyway thanks!